# Questions about Software wine?

Tags: wine

Wanted to say that Is all the software on Windows wine Is installed?
Do The software can be used such as:Adobe Dreamweaver CS6,Visual Studio 2012 On wine Installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search WineHQ's AppDB for the software you want to install (http://appdb.winehq.org/), if you find your program, you'll see that it will have ratings attached to it.

If the rating is Gold or Platinum the software should work out of the box.

If the rating is Silver, you might have to follow the instructions found on AppDB to get it running.

If the rating is Bronze or Garbage, don't bother trying, it won't work very well or at all.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes - every program can be installed in Wine. Some of them needs some libraries, but you can find info for every single app [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/) in WineHQ.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can use with Wine almost all portable windows applications. Just create a folder, let say, `Portable`, where to add the launcher from the portable application. After that, using that launcher (it will stay in the Ubuntu system tray) you can open from there all programmes from this directory. Also, most of Windows programs work portable too. Once you install them you can move all the folders inside `Portable` (just must to be in the other partition than where you have that program installed) and the launcher will see them and you can launch them. Once that is working you can uninstall them from Wine and use them portable.
Only programs that do not work as portable are system programs (antivirus, registry clean, etc) but anyway you do not need those kind of Windows programs under Linux/Ubuntu.

Sorry for my English. If you don't get what I mean just ask me.
Much more things can de done, but they must be figured out from case to case.

Comment: It would help if you stick to English instead of using slang.